# How to increase Kubeflow Jupyter notebook image name to see the complete path

Tags: docker, image, jupyter-lab, kubeflow, harbor

I have a deployment of Kubeflow. During creation of Jupyter Notebook, we have image name tags that are longer than that can be displayed in the  Docker image name list.  See the image list in the attached image. Here the names are short, but for our customer the repository URL is a long fqdn of the harbor registry URL.   Is there any configuration that can increase the visible text ?

[image]

Looking for a configuration to increase the visible text. Tried adding tags to the docker image, but this is only a suffix for the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you'd like to display the repository prefix for your Jupyter images. For this, you can set to `false` the `hideRegistry` key in the Jupyter Web App ConfigMap. By default, the value of this key is true, which hides the image repository in the user interface.

Search this ConfigMap in `kubeflow` namespace. In Kubeflow Manifests GitHub repository you can found in [spawner_ui_config.yaml](https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests/blob/14c0f9abe70c4d0ce3e021a5839a7cdd54dc572d/apps/jupyter/jupyter-web-app/upstream/base/configs/spawner_ui_config.yaml#L50) file.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. We have hideRegistry flag set to true. This appears to be a defect in KubeFlow.